# Logstash float field does not been indexed

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

The following is the configuration of logstash. When I input log into logstash, it works well as expected. All the field can be accepted by elasticsearch and the value and type of all fields is correct. However, when I view the log in kinana, it says that the cost field is not indexed so that it can't been visualized. While all the string fields are indexed. I want to visualize my float field. Anyone know what's the problem?

```
input {
    syslog {
        facility_labels=>["local0"]
    port=>515
    }
    stdin {}
}

filter{
    grok {
        overwrite => ["host", "message"]
        match => { "message" => " %{BASE10NUM:cost} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
}
mutate {
        convert => { "cost" => "float" }
    }
}
output {
    stdout{
        codec=>rubydebug
    } 
    elasticsearch{  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see the field in the kibana discovery tab or not at all? If ou see it you can go in the settings tab, select you index and reload the fields

Comment: Thank you. It's shown as indexed when I reload the fields. What's the problem? Is unable to auto-reload a problem of kibana ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibana doesn't autoreload a new field from Elastic Search. You need to reload it manually.

So you go in the Settings tab, select you index and reload the fields